# how to increase memory when using spark and R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a spark table which has 40 million records and 100 variables. I need to read the data into R memory (as.data.frame) so that I can use functions in a specific package which is not distributed.

what is the best way to fit the data into memory? should I increase spark.executor.memory, or overhead or should I change memory size on the driver?

I know that if I use Hive connection and dbgetquery(), I can bring the data into R, but I want to be able to do the data preparation with Spark and then bring the data into memory without rewriting my table to Hive.